# Quarkus does not use profile-related variables

Tags: java, configuration, quarkus, application.properties

These two links:

- https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#custom-profiles and
- https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#profile-aware-files

specify how to use different profiles in Quarkus applications. I tried both variants for my testing environment and I basically failed at both of them.

**1st variant (custom profiles)**

I have the main configuration file `src/main/resources/application.properties` which contains all main config variables but each of them has an env variable assigned as a value.

I have my test config variables also in `src/main/resources/application.properties`. Their names are the same as for the base config variables just prefixed with `%test.`.

When I do not have any environment variable set related to any config variable, then `mvn -Dquarkus.test.profile=test clean verify` works as expected - the values from the config variables prefixed with `%test.` are used during the tests.

However, as soon as I specify any env variable which is used as a value for some config property, the test value for this config property is not used anymore but the value from the variable. This breaks the expected behavior also in my CI/CD pipelines.

**2nd variant (profile aware files)**

I have a main configuration file `src/main/resources/application.properties` and also I have a test profile file `src/main/resources/application-test.properties`. I have the same scenario with variables as in the 1st variant. Meaning that in the main config file I have for example `my.property=${MY_PROPERTY}` and in the test profile config I have `my.property=dummyValue`.

If I do not set env variable `MY_PROPERTY`, then the `dummyValue` value is used for `my.property` during runtime. But when I set the env variable `MY_PROPERTY`, then the `dummyValue` is completely ignored when I run `mvn -Dquarkus.test.profile=test clean verify`. Therefore this breaks my testing environment again.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if understand your problem but for me its looking ok, If you check priority of the config sources env variables have more priority than properties files https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference#configuration-sources . For a given variable present in the property file if you specify the value in a environmental variable, the value picked should be the one from the environmental variable. Is this your problem or what you are saying is that quarkus is doing something different

Comment: @JavierToja you are completely right. I did not realize that env variables have preference over application.properties file. In the end I solved it using `QuarkusTestProfile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly as @JavierToja mentioned in his comment - the environment variables have higher priority than properties.

Therefore for testing purposes I did not create a test profile via properties like `%test.my.property=myValue` nor by creating `application-test.properties` as the values from env variables in the non-test profile get  preferred and I would not achieve the desired behavior this way.

In the end I solved my problem with preferring test profile over the environment variables in the "main" profile (`application.properties`) by implementing `QuarkusTestProfile` class [1]. I overridden the `getConfigOverrides` method in such way that it returns a map of key value pairs where the key is the property name that I want to override and the value is the value for this property that I want to prefer to a value from an environment variable.

[1] https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#testing_different_profiles